# Filtering Dataframe by Row

Tags: python, pandas, filter, dataframe, keyerror

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
CompanyName User Issue  Equipment Issue No  TBD Total
Customer1   0   0   35  0   35
Customer2   0   0   28  0   28
Customer3   2   3   12  0   17
Customer4   5   1   8   0   14
```

I want to remove Customer1 and Customer2 from the table. I am trying to use

```
df= df[[c for c in df.columns if c not in ['Customer1','Customer2']]]
```

and

```
df=df[(~df.isin('Customer2','Customer2'))]
```

and

```
df=df[~df['CompanyName'].str.contains('Customer1')]
```

I'm not getting any errors, but Customer1 and Customer2 are still showing up in the plot!

```
df.columns.tolist

Out[85]: <bound method Index.tolist of Index([u'CompanyName', u'User Issue', u'Equipment Issue', u'No', u'TBD'], dtype='object')>

sortedtotal.columns.tolist()
Out[93]: 
['CompanyName',
 'User Issue',
 'Equipment Issue',
 'No',
 'TBD']
```

Comment: Is it your index? if so then `df.loc[~df.index.isin(['Customer1','Customer2'])]` should work, also show the output from `df.columns.tolist()`

Comment: I have a tough time believing that's the output from `df.columns.tolist()`.  It looks a lot more like the output from `df.columns.tolist` (without the parentheses, so meaning the method itself, not the result of calling it.)

Comment: @EdChum If I reset the index, I get rid of the KeyError, but Customer1 and Customer2 are still in the dataframe.

Comment: @DSM You're right, I forgot the parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the index:

```
df.reset_index()
```

You are then getting an autoincrementing index, but your customers index will become a column.  More here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

After that your commands to filter the data should work.

EDIT:
Use this filtering approach: 
df = df[~df['Company Name'].isin(['customer1', 'customer2'])]

Comment: This helped the KeyError, but it still isn't filtering the elements.

Comment: try this filtering approach:
    df = df[~df['Company Name'].isin(['customer1', 'customer2'])

Comment: Yes! This worked, though it needs a closing bracket on the end. Thank you!

Comment: Great.  Updated answer to reflect that :)